# Add CSS class with hook

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

I have a search box using [custom_search module](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search). I am trying to add multiple classes to the *input* field using a hook.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
<?php
function mytheme_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
      $form['keys']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'custom_search-keys','form-search','form-control';
    }
```

But it does not add the classes to the search box input field?

Comment: Is this the correct hook? In Drupal 8, you must pass $form_state as an instance of FormStateInterface. Can you verify the code is being hit?

Comment: As well as verify that the attribute key is correct, when validating that this code is hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, add class as array.

```
$form['keys']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('custom_search-keys','form-search','form-control'));
```